# Facebook login through FirebaseAuth UI fails

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I've set up the Firebase Auth UI API in my Android project and Google signin works perfectly, but facebook login always fails, even though I set it up in developers.facebook.com. The error is presented below

```java
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Developer error
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.data.ProviderUtils$1.then(ProviderUtils.java:219)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.util.data.ProviderUtils$1.then(ProviderUtils.java:195)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:768)
```

Anyone knows what this is due to? The error is not at least a bit enlightening...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FirebaseUI, you must put this exact string in strings.xml:

APPID
The APPID can be found on your developers.facebook.com dashboard.

See [Firebase auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md) readme

Also be sure to add your android key hash and OAuth firebase URL in the facebook app.